# Proving a linear map of polynomials is surjective

Tags: polynomials, proof-explanation, linear-transformations

I am trying to solve the following problem.

> Let $F$ be the field with $q$ elements and $V$ the vector space polynomials of polynomials with degree less than or equal to $n$ over $F$. Define $\phi: V \to F^q$ by $\phi(f) = (f(0), f(1), \ldots, f(q-1))$. Prove that $\phi$ is surjective.

I'm having some trouble getting started on this. A general polynomial in $V$ has the form
$$
f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + \ldots + a_n x^n. 
$$
I want to find some way to construct this polynomial in such a way that I can guarantee that, given any element of $x = (x_0, \ldots, x_{q-1}) \in F^q$, this polynomial $f(i) = x_i$. In general, I think that I can say that an $n$ degree polynomial is determined once I know $n + 1$ points, but I don't think this applies to this case because, presumably, $q$ is much smaller than $n$. The other method I had in mind was to set up a system of equations:
\begin{align*}
f(0) &= a_0 + a_1 0 + a_2 0^2 + \ldots + a_n 0^n \implies f(0) = a_0 \\
f(1) &= a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + a_2 + \ldots + a_n \\
f(2) &= a_0 + 2a_1 + 4a_2 + 8a_3 + \ldots + a_n 2^n \\
\ddots \\
f(q-1) &= a_0 + a_1 (q-1) + a_2 (q-1)^2 + \ldots + a_n (q-1)^n.
\end{align*}
All this let me do is determine that I can choose a polynomial whose constant component is the first element of the vector in $F^q$ of interest. Otherwise, I have a system of $q$ equations in $n$ unknowns and don't know of a way to check that these equations can simultaneously be satisfied for any choice of $F_q$.

Comment: Is there some relationship between $q$ and $n$ that you left out?  Otherwise, it seems like in the case $n=0$, all polynomials in $V$ would be constant and the statement would clearly be false.

Comment: You don't specify a relationship between $n$ and $q$;  you need $n \ge q-1$. Are you familiar with Lagrange interpolation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Comment: There is also a slick proof when $n = q-1$ where you instead argue that $\phi$ is injective, then that the source and target have the same dimension, from which it follows that $\phi$ is surjective.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, I unintentionally left this out, sorry. I'm slightly familiar with Lagrange interpolation, but haven't before proved that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The finite field stuff is a red herring. The following more general fact is true over any field:

> **Interpolation theorem:** Let $F$ be a field and $x_0, x_1, \dots x_n \in F$ be distinct. Let $V$ be the vector space of polynomials of degree $\le n$, and consider the linear map

> $$\phi : V \ni f(x) \mapsto (f(x_0), f(x_1), \dots f(x_n)) \in F^{n+1}.$$

> Then $\phi$ is an isomorphism. Explicitly, this means that for every $(y_0, \dots y_{n+1}) \in F^{n+1}$, there exists a unique polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $\le n$, the **interpolating** polynomial, such that $f(x_i) = y_i$.

The easy half of the claim is that $\phi$ is injective. To see this we just observe that $\phi(f) = 0$ means $f(x_0) = f(x_1) = \dots = f(x_n) = 0$, so $f$ must be divisible by $\prod (x - x_i)$. But this is a polynomial of degree $n+1$, so this is impossible unless $f = 0$.

The interesting half of the claim is that $\phi$ is surjective. This implies surjectivity if we take polynomials of any degree $\ge n$ since we can always take the interpolating polynomial of minimal degree. If we allow higher degree polynomials the interpolating polynomial just won't be unique in general. Here are three proofs.

*Proof 1.* Since $V$ and $F^{n+1}$ both have dimension $n+1$, an injective linear map between them is necessarily surjective (by rank-nullity). $\Box$

This proof is the shortest but arguably the least satisfying since it doesn't tell you anything about how to construct the interpolating polynomial.

*Proof 2.* If we write $\phi$ out explicitly using the monomial basis $\{ 1, x, \dots x^n \}$ of $V$, we get a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix). Now we can use any of the standard evaluations of the [Vandermonde determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix#Determinant): for example, the determinant is a homogeneous polynomial in the $x_i$ of degree $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ which vanishes when any two of the $x_i$ are equal (since in this case $\phi$ is no longer injective), so it must be divisible by every polynomial of the form $x_i - x_j, i < j$ and there are $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ of these. (This argument is explained in more detail at the Wikipedia link.)

Once we have the closed form of the Vandermonde determinant we can see that it doesn't vanish if the $x_i$ are distinct, meaning that the Vandermonde matrix is invertible in this case, so $\phi$ is an isomorphism as desired. $\Box$

This proof is somewhat more explicit but it reduces the question of how to actually calculate the interpolating polynomial to inverting the Vandermonde matrix, which can be done but requires evaluating a bunch of other Vandermonde-like determinants.

*Proof 3.* We can construct the inverse of $\phi$ explicitly as follows. First, consider the question of how to construct a polynomial $f_j$ such that $f_j(x_i) = 0$ unless $i = j$ for a specific $j$ and such that $f_j(x_j) = 1$. This polynomial has to be divisible by $\prod_{i \neq j} (x - x_i)$, which takes the value $\prod_{i \neq j} (x_j - x_i)$ at $x = x_j$. So we just divide by this, obtaining the [Lagrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)

$$f_j(x) = \frac{\prod_{i \neq j} (x - x_i)}{\prod_{i \neq j} (x_j - x_i)}.$$

The Lagrange polynomial explicitly computes $\phi^{-1}(0, \dots 1, \dots 0)$ where $1$ occurs in the $j^{th}$ index. Since $\phi^{-1}$ is linear this computes $\phi^{-1}$ in general by linearity, namely: the unique polynomial of degree $\le n$ such that $f(x_i) = y_i$ must be given by

$$f(x) = \sum_{j=0}^n y_j f_j(x).$$

This completes the proof. $\Box$

Arguably this is the best proof; it doesn't even require explicitly knowing much linear algebra, one just needs to think carefully about basic properties of polynomials. I do think it's valuable to see how it is compatible with the more abstract proofs requiring more linear algebra. The Lagrange polynomials actually amount to an explicit description of the inverse of the Vandermonde matrix.